# Как сохранить массив List в SharedPreference?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-shared-preferences

вот моя переменная и лист

```
 val basket = ArrayList<ProductInBasket>()
```

я не знаю как сохранить этот лист в SharedPreference

и заполняю массив при клике добавить в корзину

```
 app.basket.add(ProductInBasket(app.currentProduct!!))

//аpp -класс
class MyApp: Application() {
    var currentProduct: Product?=null;
    val basket = ArrayList<ProductInBasket>()

}
```

//класс товары в корзине

```
class ProductInBasket {
    var product: Product
    var quantity: Int = 1
    constructor(product: Product){
        this.product = product
    }
}
//класс продукты

 data class  Product(
        val id: Int,
        val Title: String,
        val productTypeID: Int,
        val articleNumber: String,
        val description: String?,
        val image: String,

        val minCost: String,
        val   Quantity:Int,

        )
```

Окно где выводиться детальная информация о товаре ,а также заполняется массив при клике добавить в корзину

```
class DetaileInfo : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var app: MyApp
    private lateinit var testV: TextView
    private lateinit var conten: TextView
    private lateinit var im: ImageView
    private lateinit var pric: TextView



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detaile_info)
        app = applicationContext as MyApp

  


        val product = app.currentProduct;
        if (product == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Что-то пошло не так!.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            finish();
            return;
        } else {
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.title).setText(product.Title)
            //findViewById<TextView>(R.id.article).setText(product.articleNumber)
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.priceProd).setText("Цена: ${product.minCost.toString()} руб.")
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.priceProd1).setText("Цена: ${product.minCost.toString()}P")
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.Quantity).setText("В наличии: ${product.Quantity.toString()} шт.")
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.description).setText(product.description)


    }

    private fun sssd() {

        startActivity(Intent(this, korzina::class.java))

    }

  
    fun ADD1(view: View) {

        var found=false
        for (i in 0 until  app.basket.size) {
            val item = app.basket[i]
            if (item.product.id == app.currentProduct!!.id) {
                found=true
                item.quantity++
                break
            }
        }

        if (!found)
            app.basket.add(ProductInBasket(app.currentProduct!!))


        val fab: View = findViewById(R.id.btn1)
        fab.visibility = View.GONE;
        val fab1: View = findViewById(R.id.btn2)
        fab1.visibility = View.VISIBLE;
        val fab3: View = findViewById(R.id.Quantityy)
        fab3.visibility = View.VISIBLE;

    }


    fun sss(view: View) {
        //  app.currentProduct
        startActivity(Intent(this, korzina::class.java))


    }


    fun ADDDDplus(view: View) {
        var found=false
        for (i in 0 until  app.basket.size) {
            val item = app.basket[i]
            if (item.product.id == app.currentProduct!!.id) {
                found=true
                item.quantity++
                break
            }
        }

        if (!found)
            app.basket.add(ProductInBasket(app.currentProduct!!))

        val toast1 = Toast.makeText(
            applicationContext,
            "Добавлено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT

        )
        toast1.show()


    }

    fun saveArrayList(list: java.util.ArrayList<String?>?, key: String?) {
        val prefs: SharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity)
        val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = prefs.edit()
        val gson = Gson()
        val json: String = gson.toJson(list)
        editor.putString(key, json)
        editor.apply()
    }


}
```

Comment: в чем конкрентно вопрос - "не знаю как сохранить список" или "не знаю как сохранить в шаредпреференсес"?

Comment: может лучше сохранять в преференс только id-шники товаров? Если нужно прям списки - тогда приложи код ProductInBasket.

Comment: Я код изменил ,у меня пока просто заполняется массив ,List и я хотел бы сохранить его в шаредпреференс и потом уже буду post запрос отправлять и добавалять в бд mysgl

Comment: запятую нужно ставить ПОСЛЕ слова, БЕЗ ПРОБЕЛА. После запятой - пробел. А не так, как у вас.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sharedPreferences` хранят типы String, Int, Boolean, Long, Float
Если вам приниципиально схранить в `sharedPreferences` список, то одним из вариантов будет преобразовать объект в `json` строку и сохранять его ввиде строки

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
import dagger.android.AndroidInjection
import ru.sarawan.android.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import ru.sarawan.android.model.data.AppState
import ru.sarawan.android.model.data.ProductsItem

class ExampleActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private companion object {
        //ключ по которому мы получаем и под которым сохраняем данные
        const val SHARED_KEY = "SHARED_KEY"
    }
    var list = ArrayList<ProductsItem>()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        initListData()

        //получили список из sharedPref
        val newList = getArrayList()
        //добавили полученный список newList в список list, можно list = newList
        list.addAll(newList)
    }

    private fun initListData() {
        //добавили данные в список
        list.add(ProductsItem(quantity = 1))
        list.add(ProductsItem(quantity = 2))
        list.add(ProductsItem(quantity = 3))
        list.add(ProductsItem(quantity = 4))
        list.add(ProductsItem(quantity = 5))
        list.add(ProductsItem(quantity = 6))
        list.add(ProductsItem(quantity = 7))
        //сохранили
        saveArrayList(list)
    }
    private fun saveArrayList(list: ArrayList<ProductsItem>) {
        val prefs: SharedPreferences = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = prefs.edit()
        val gson = Gson()
        val json: String = gson.toJson(list)
        editor.putString(SHARED_KEY, json)
        editor.apply()
    }

    private fun  getArrayList() : ArrayList<ProductsItem>{
        val prefs: SharedPreferences = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val gson = Gson()
        val json = prefs.getString(SHARED_KEY, null);
        val type = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<ProductsItem>>() {}.type
        return gson.fromJson(json, type);
    }
}
```

Для использования библиотеки Gson надо в build.gradle подключить зависимость в блоке dependencies    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6', а после синхронизироваться

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.ifr0z.fabuserlocation.example"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    //------------------------------------------------
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    //------------------------------------------------
}
```

Но для списков обычно используют локальную базу данных, а не `sharedPreferences`, почитайте о `sqllite` и room в *Android* и используйте их для хранения полей объектов

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135546/discussion-on-answer-by-dmitry-avdoshin----list--sharedprefer).